# JavaScript link working in Chrome but not in Firefox

Tags: javascript, html, ruby-on-rails-3

In my Rails project, I have in HTML file

```
<a href='#' id="show_advanced">Show advanced options</a>
```

Then in JavaScript/JQuery

```
  jQuery("#show_advanced").click(function() { // if link is clicked
      event.preventDefault(); // don't go to another page
      if (jQuery('.advanced_option').is(':hidden')) { // if it is hidden, slide down
        jQuery('.advanced_option').slideDown();
        jQuery("#show_advanced").html("Hide advanced options");
      } else { // if not, slide up
        jQuery('.advanced_option').slideUp();
        jQuery("#show_advanced").html("Show advanced options");
      }
  });
```

which displays the advanced options of a form. In Chrome, this works fine. But in FireFox, the link just takes me to the page `.../#`, which is not the correct thing. How can I fix it?

Comment: Could you show the contents of your click callback? Also, what errors show up in the console when trying this on firefox?

Comment: I've edited to show the content of the callback. I don't see any error in the console.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would assume that you aren't preventing the default behavior of the anchor tag. If you are on the page http://example.com/index.html and there is an anchor with a hash + text for the href, then that link will take the user to the element with the text for the id.

```
<a href='#end'>Click Me!</a>
...
<div id='end'>content</div>
```

If you want to prevent the browser from this standard behavior, then you need to use the event's preventDefault function. The key is to pass the event to the callback function:

```
jQuery("#show_advanced").click(function(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  ...
}
```

You're missing the event parameter from the callback declaration!

Comment: Wow, that's really subtle. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You actually do not need the href='#'. Just leave it as an anchor.

```
<a id="show_advanced">Show advanced options</a>
<script> 
    $("#show_advanced").click(function () {
        console.log("clicked");
    });
</script>
```

Comment: While true, the problem is that the click event callback isn't preventing the default behavior of the anchor. Leaving the href blank implies that the page should be reloaded. The hash at least doesn't make a round trip to the server. EDIT: I see what you're suggesting, nm.

Comment: Ok, @DougMiller your suggesting he has a runtime error in the function . Good thought/ catch.

Comment: @user1944367 I tried removing the `href`, and now clicking in Firefox does nothing.